# Как идентифицировать пользователя и заранее понять чего он (возможно) хочет?

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно понять, что хочет пользователь. Например, если он зашел на сайт через google по запросу "мотоцикл" или на самом сайте в поиске искал мотоцикл или просто заходил в раздел с мотоциклами а на сайте есть трактора, велосипеды, авто и мотоциклы, то виджет "Возможно вас заинтересует" должен подсунуть ему согласно какой-то логике пару-тройку мотоциклов, менюшка (которая допустим стандартно выводит "АВТО, ТРАКТОРА, ВЕЛО, МОТО") должна будет вывести МОТО на первом месте. Вообщем я надеюсь идея ясна. Сайт должен знать пользователя в лицо.

Помимо этого, если пользователь зайдет на сайт через месяц под другим браузером, возможно даже из под другой ОС, то сайт должен его узнать.

Собственно вопросы:

1. Как узнать пользователя?
   Если писать в куку, то при смене браузера нужная модель работать не будет. Если запоминать IP, то они вроде как бывают непостоянные. Я понимаю что 100%-ную узнаваемость реализовать если и можно, то сложно. Какой вариант по вашему будет золотой серединой?
2. Если юзер пришел с поисковой системы (бинг, гугль, яндекс, мэйл, аск, рамблер), как это у себя отследить и выудить текст запроса?

**UPD**: Забыл отметить то, что всё это должно работать без регистрации.

Answer (score 10):

1. Как узнать пользователя?

   С вашими условиями — только через распознавание лица с веб-камеры, честное слово.
2. Если пользователь пришел с поисковой системы

   Если браузер разрешает смотреть информацию о предыдущей странице (реферрер), то через `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` Если не позволяет — никак, чаще всего. Иногда, правда, счетчики, стоящие на сайте узнают свою же систему по кукам, но вряд ли они поделятся своими данными с сайтом.

Как еще узнать пользователя? Регистрация неслучайно придумана. Наверно, она зачем-то нужна. Кстати, она может быть через OPENID или через соцсети, тогда отдельной процедуры регистрации проходить не надо.

**UPD:**

Без регистрации, без аналога open ID, без надежды на куки и инфу о браузере... Только через вебку. См пункт 1.

**UPD2:** Но так вы, наверное, поленитесь (и все поленятся): можно запоминать для каждого хита перемещения мыши: траектория, аккуратность кликов, что выделял... Что-то типа тепловой карты, но много более совершенное. Потом анализировать эти движения: считается, что для одного и того же человека есть типичный набор привычных жестов, есть привычное место на кнопке, куда он нажимает, есть стандартное время для кликов и стандартная скорость/ускорение для мыши. Вечная память серваку...

Comment: очень понравилась идея про то, что каждый человек ведет себя по разному на сайте))) возможно в будущем и будет создана самообучающаяся система, которая будет идентифицировать пользователей. На данный момент такие эксперименты могут позволить себе только очень крупные проекты, в частности, соц сети FB && VK

Comment: ок. Если выбирать между ip, cookie и регистрацией что бы Вы выбрали?
Можно ip и куку хранить на случай если Ip переменный. Сейчас опишу алгоритм мин через 5. оцените.

Comment: регистрацию, однозначно. Только не простыню из 54 вопросов, а поле ввода email или логина: после ввода либо высылается, либо показывается логин.
Cookie же использовать исключительно, чтобы пользователю не приходилось каждый раз входить: упрощает жизнь.

Comment: Пользователь нынче ленивый. А бывают и такие кому не хватает мозгов через тот же ulogin зарегаться. Там делов в 2 клика =\

ВОобщем буду делать как Вы и сказали. вход/регистрация + вечная кука

Comment: ip вообще для идентификации не надо использовать: не те времена. Юзеров много, айпи мало. Это должно быть лишь достаточным условием, но не необходимым: если айпи не тот - повод для беспокойства, особенно, если произведен доступ одновременно с двух IP. Выкидывать не надо, но на заметку - поставить. Если тот же айпи, те же куки, тот же браузер и ОС, тот же логин - все ок, это с большой вероятностью НАШ человек.

Comment: А я вообще на сайты с регистрацией ходить не люблю, а если там еще и реклама...

Comment: > На данный момент такие эксперименты могут позволить себе только очень крупные проекты, в частности, соц сети FB && VK

Угу, например, социальная география. Однажды по открытым профилям в одноклассниках была построена полная карта воинских частей РФ, что вообще-то является секретной информацией.

Answer (score 4):

Откуда посетитель пришёл - очевидно надо узнавать из поля Referer.
А вот отслеживать посетителя без регистрации... Оно конечно можно, есть всякие [EverCookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) есть [KISSmetrics](http://www.kissmetrics.com/how-it-works) и т.д. А оно вам правда надо?

Comment: правда надо.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы запросили называется вебвизор. Он отслеживает действия пользователя, если есть JS.
https://metrika.yandex.ru/promo/webvisor