# Реализация уникального количества просмотров страницы

Tags: алгоритм, php

Как правильно сделать это? Используя базу данных.

Comment: абсолютно правильно - никак. Можно что-то мудрить с куками и т.д., но как известно куки чистятся, изменяются ручками и т.д. и т.п. По IP тоже не вариант - далеко не у всех статический IP (более того у большинства он динамический)

Comment: Понятно, только относительно.

Comment: @exec спасибо большое (сами знаете за что).

Comment: @ReinRaus :)

Answer (score 3):

Если страницу показывать только авторизованным пользователям, то можно сделать количество просмотров очень даже уникальным. :-))) А вообще, конечно, каждый просмотр и так уникален, даже если он уже в пятый раз от одного и того же человека. Я бы засчитывала. :-)

Comment: Философский подход. :-)

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, я сегодня же был на философии. Не напоминайте.
И тут тоже ничего нового не услышал. Но +100 за желание помочь.

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, здесь только один минус - заставить пользователя зарегистрироваться (или хотя бы авторизоваться, с помощью ВК, ФБ и прочих).

Comment: Это да и абсолютному большинству нереально лениво это делать, а наши проблемы их не интересуют...

Comment: @Dex @AlexWindHope А если заставить выбрать или ввести дату своего рождения, присоединить IP и получить хеш? -))) Уникальность нарушиться только если в одной семье близнецы или если каким-то чудом один и тот же айпи будет дан двум людям с одинаковой датой рождения или случится коллизия. -)

Comment: @exec Спасибки огромное. -*

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, а что мне мешает другую дату рождения поставить?

Comment: @Dex, совесть. :-) Ну да, не подумала. :-(

Comment: Мысль с датой рождения неплохая, но тогда, как по мне - лучше на куках делать. Как я уже писал выше - куки, мягко говоря, не самое надежное хранилище данных, но что поделаешь.

Но так хоть не нужно заставлять пользователя что-то вводить.

<troll> А что если заставить пользователя вводить дату своего рождения с точностью до секунды? :D
Тогда даже близнецы не прокатят </troll>

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я не смогу зарегистрироваться - не знаю секунд своего рождения.

Comment: @exec - слово **troll** вам о чем-то говорит? В календарь смотрели? :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а я разве серьезно ответил? :D

Comment: А кто вас знает ;D

Answer (score 1):

Уникальность пользователя можно определять двумя путями (известными мне):

- IP
- Cookie

Так же, можно применять их в связке, анализировать браузер и т.д. и т.п.

**Рассмотрим первый пункт:**
IP посетителя хранится в `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. При загрузке страницы Вам необходимо проанализировать значение этой переменной и, если такой айпи не найден в базе, то добавить его. Например:
Таблица в mysql будет иметь вид: 
**id | page_name | ip**

```
$page_name = "имя_страницы"
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ip ='".$ip."' AND page_name='".$page_name."'") or die(mysql_error());
//Если такого айпи нет в базе, то делаем инсерт
if ( mysql_num_rows($fetch) == 0 ) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO uniquehits(ip, page_name) VALUES('$ip', '$page_name')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Получить количество уникальных просмотров можно с помощью запроса:

```
$counttotal = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) cnt FROM uniquehits WHERE page_name='".$page_name."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**Рассмотрим второй пункт:**

```
// Проверяем, был ли уже установлен Cookie.
// Если нет, то устанавливаем
// С временем жизни до 2029 года
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) setcookie("visited","1",0x6FFFFFFF);
```

Проверить установлен ли куки можно с помощью: @$_COOKIE['visited']

---

Как уже было сказано, нет идеального варианта. IP может изменится, куки можно удалить, но такой анализ даст вам хотя бы приблизительную информацию.

Comment: За старание конечно спасибо, но ничего нового не узнал.

Comment: IP -- @Vitalii Maslianok, у меня, например, 3G модем от beeline. Дальше объяснять про IP? (На ppp0 адрес 172.19.188.96)

Comment: я бы при первом посещении ставил куку и запоминал айпи, потом поверял куку, если ее нет, то искал бы айпи в базе.
Я уже сказал, что данный способ не претендует на 100% (или даже 90%) правильность... Но даст понимание общей ситуации.
Хотите максимально правильные результаты - ставьте счетчики от Google || Yandex

Answer (score 0):

Это не ответ. Просто возможно много буковок будет,, поэтому пишу в ответ. Как мы все видим проблема идентификации пользователя всё ещё стоит. На днях задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/94703/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82) на который так и не получил удовлетворяющего ответа. Товарищи, умы, хэшкодовцы, ... давайте уже решим вопрос идентификации личности в сети без регистрации и всяких входов через социалки. Тот же гугль и яндекс не просят никакой регистрации. Понятно, что там базы немалые, но они и расчитаны на весь интернет. Давайте найдём лучшее решение для простого сервиса, а не гиганта вроде гугля? Если не ip и не печеньки и не социалки то что?

Comment: Да не существует решения, дающего защиту от всех трюков (да даже и не всех тоже). Определите для себя, что нужно и какие ошибки считать приемлемыми.

Comment: А пока что ждём времени когда каждому жителю планеты будут встраивать идентификатор прямо в тело, затем этот айди будет использоваться для доступа в интернет, и передаваться в суперглобальном массиве. :-)

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, как очередной шаг к этому можно рассматривать [геолокацию](http://herozero.ho.ua/html5/11.html). Естественно, это лишние телодвижения от человека, достаточно спорный метод, но его рассмотреть тоже можно.

Comment: @Dex - местонахождение пользователя тоже не показатель. И что если человек, например, едет в поезде, или вышел от друга с его компа или с кафе со своего лаптопа? =)

На самом деле, как верно подметил @alexlz - 100% верного решения здесь нет и, пока, быть не может. Конечно если собрать воедино все подходы - мы получим максимально приблеженный результат, но абсолютно верного, пока, получить невозможно.

@Виталий Кустов - миксуйте все и не прогадаете ;DDD

Comment: @AlexWindHope, у меня еще первое апреля, по меньшей мере минут 25 точно будет, поэтому миксовать и миксовать. Вы правы, все можно обойти.

Comment: Т.е. чаще всего мы получим результат как при проверке поддержки того или иного кодэка в HTML5 audio и video, а именно - не true, false. А true, false и, мой любимый, **maybe** :D

По сути, в некоторых случаях, код превратился бы в гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Тут сыграет еще роль величина "[но зачем?](http://www.gamer.ru/system/attached_images/images/000/411/621/original/1320276.jpg?1313841218)" и "ожидаемого уровня надежности метода".

Comment: Я вообще считаю что это разговоры "ниочем", ставишь себе счетчик и радуешься жизни (чего чего, а этого добра хватает).

Comment: Ага, именно ни о чем! Для этого эта тема и была, видимо, создана.

Comment: Хотя нет, пофантазировать, помечтать и т.д. :DDD